How to fix "The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed" when debugging unit tests for ASPNET Zero project
When I "Run" a unit test, it works fine.  When I "Debug", the test run always aborts, and I always see this in the Output window:
========== Starting test run ==========
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.8.2+699d445a1a (64-bit .NET 8.0.8)
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.25]   Starting:    MyProject.Tests
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed
========== Test run aborted: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms ==========

I'd just like to be able to debug unit tests.

I am having the same problem. Interesting to note, is that I only have the problem with (N)unit tests that implement my TestBase, which makes use of an SQLite database.

The problem for me stemmed from not having the AbpZeroLicenseCode configuration item available. I had it in user secrets, but the secrets weren't being picked up.
